# IIS: Hidden segments and custom errors clash

Tags: php, iis, web-config, custom-error-pages

I need to secure the `/app` directory and its files from probing. I tried using `<hiddenSegment>` in a `web.config` file and it works nicely… except that when I add an IIS custom error page, it does not work.

### Application structure

```
.
├── app
│   ├── template
│   │   ├── footer.php
│   │   ├── header.php
│   │   └── index.php
│   ├── error-handler.php
│   ├── footer.php
│   └── header.php
├── template
│   ├── css
│   └── js
└── web.config
```

*The entire `/app` directory needs to be hidden; its contents must be safe from probing.*

### `web.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/app/error-handler.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <remove statusCode="403" />
            <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/app/error-handler.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <add segment="app" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've been really struggling to try to both hide the `/app` directory and make IIS serve the error handler in `/app/error-handler.php`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The `<directoryBrowse>` tag is for directory browsing and you might not need hidden segment at all.

Comment: @LexLi No, that is not what I want. Currently, someone could make an HTTP GET request like this: `GET /scripts/error.php?404;http://www.example.com/some-seo-friendly-url HTTP/1.1` and it would return the same as `GET /some-seo-friendly-url HTTP/1.1`. That is what I want to disable. Also, requests like `GET /scripts/header.php HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: @LexLi Is it possible to achieve the same result using permissions? I basically want no one except for IIS to be able to execute those files.

Answer (score 0):

how about creating another folder underneath the app folder (myFolder) and move everything except the error_handler.php inside that new folder  (myFolder) and adjust the Hiddensegments tag accordingly. This might require some adjustments to your code.

Or just move the error-handler.php to one level up and adjust the CustomErrors Tag accordingly. Not sure if it will break anything.

Comment: I could, but that only solves part of the problem and does not address the real issue.